# how to open webview inside facebook messenger on desktop web browser

Tags: webview, bots, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to implement some features inside a web view in facebook messenger. on the phone the webview is opening fine, but in desctop web browser the webview is opening inside a new tab.
im using the following feature:

`buttons:[{
            type: "web_url",
            url: "https://www.oculus.com/en-us/rift/",
            title: "Open Web URL",
            webview_height_ratio: "compact",
            messenger_extensions: true,
          }`

I know that maybe it is supposed to open like this but you all can agree that if I'm implementing a custom feature inside the conversation it would be mach better to open it inside a small webview in the conversation.
does anyone knows if this even possible?

Comment: I'm very much interested in the same. Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to follow the steps in these [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions).

Make sure to read the docs for desktop and add the `X-Frame-Options` header. The troubleshooting section in the same docs is your friend.

Two caveats:

- `X-Frame-Options` header does not seem to be enough for firefox. I'm in the process of building a bot using webview, and when I figure out which headers to send to make firefox work, I will post them here. **EDIT** due to some bugs within the platform on the web, I've postponed this project.
- There seem to be a problem with getting page-scoped user ids on desktop. Read my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850784/facebook-webview-fails-when-shared).

Comment: You have to both things set: the headers AND the messenger_extensions set to true for this to work.